# How to get a number from a changing variable?

Tags: java, game-physics

I'm currently trying to make something like a trail that follows an object. Well, basically I just create a "trail object" every second at X,Y of the main object. However, I can't make it work.

This the movement code for the main object.

```
dx = ((Math.sin(speed)*20);
    speed = speed + 0.09;
    x = x + dx;
```

My idea was that for making a trail I just need to subtract dx from x, so it would look like that

```
tick = tick + gameTimer.getDelay();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (tick > 1000*i)
            {
                g2d.drawOval(x-dx, y, 50, 50);
            }

        }
```

but apparently my theory is wrong and therefore I ask for your help people.

P.S. There is no code for "y" because I don't need it yet.
P.S.S I know that I'm missing a lot of details, so if you need some more info let me know and I'll paste some more code

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your theory?

Comment: Instead of just being at one place the trail objects follow the main object

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by `trail object` if it's not supposed to follow the main object.

Comment: Imagine a circle(the main object) moving at a straight line. Let's say x=x+5 so at every *second* it moves 5 units right. I want to draw a circle(trail object) at every let's say 2 seconds, so it looks like a trail.

Comment: How are you drawing the circle(s)?  Save the locations of the trailing circles in a list so you can draw all of them when drawing the moving object.

Comment: Yup, seems like a FIFO queue would do it... `LinkedList` does come to mind...